# How can I run tests against web ACLs in AWS to be sure the rules are working as intended?

Tags: amazon-web-services, testing, firewall

1.) BotControl

2.) AmazonIpReputationList

3.) AnonymousIp

4.) CommonRuleSet

5.) KnownBadInputs

6.) LinuxRuleSet

7.) SQL injection

these are all rule sets I have set in place but is there a way for me to tests against them to make sure they are working as intended?

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

basically you would like to test your rules, here is my 2 cents

1. Counting the web requests that match the rules in a web ACL

> Configure all the rules in a web ACL to count web requests
> Set the default action for the web ACL to allow requests

2. Viewing a sample of the web requests that API Gateway CloudFront or an Application Load Balancer has forwarded to AWS WAF Classic

> In the AWS WAF Classic console, you can view a sample of the requests
> that API
> Gateway CloudFront or an Application Load Balancer has forwarded to AWS WAF
> Classic for inspection. For each sampled request, you can view detailed data
> about the request, such as the originating IP address and the headers included
> in the request. You also can view which rule the request matched, and whether
> the rule is configured to allow or block requests.

3. Logging and monitoring web ACL traffic

> You can enable logging to get detailed information about traffic that
> is analyzed by your web ACL. Logged information includes the time that
> AWS WAF received a web request from your AWS resource, detailed
> information about the request, and details about the rules that the
> request matched. You can send your logs to an Amazon CloudWatch Logs
> log group, an Amazon Simple Storage Service (Amazon S3) bucket, or an
> Amazon Kinesis Data Firehose.

please refer this [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/waf/latest/developerguide/classic-web-acl-testing.html#classic-web-acl-testing-count) for more information.

Comment: For the first one is there a way for me to perhaps send custom requests myself to be sure the counter is working? The issue I'm coming across is that I have the counter and allow on but since there is no traffic currently it does not count anything, I hope I'm phrasing my question correctly. Thank you for replying.